# is it possible to a whole number to change to matrix

Tags: matrices

I have an equation 
$$ 1 - \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$

is it possible to change to the whole number,1 to a matrix and solve this equation? If I can , how do I change it into a matrix?

Comment: This operation is not defined. Maybe if you give some more context someone can help you.

Comment: Can you revisit your question? You said *I have an equation*. But what you wrote is not an equation: there is no equal sign.

Comment: I suspect "1" means, or should mean, the identity matrix in your "equation".